# Optimising LED output without destroying them, factors, temperature

Tags: led

I want to maximise output of LEDs. The problem is I don't have the datasheets, only absolute maximum ratings. But even when operating below those ratings, I keep blowing them.

How should I determine best operating current? Trial and error? I'm considering running 10 or more overnight at a given current to if any blow. If this is the best way, then what other factors should I take into account? I suspect temperature is important - please can someone shed light on the relationships temperature has on LED operation?

I presume higher temperature decreases the forward voltage required to achieve a given current? For a given forward current, does the temperature affect lifespan? (Within reasonable temperatures e.g. -10 to 60 degrees c)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a datasheet?  Following the recommended forward current is usually fine and shouldn't result in LEDs blowing.

Answer (score 1):

Learn how measure junction temperature.
One method is measure the forward voltage with 1mA in a oven and make a chart.
Then switch the Led from say 10 mA to test current and measure both voltages to determine a) junction temperature b) ESR of LED

Next you need to measure your heat sink thermal resistance.  Rja= ΔT/W   ['C/W].

Your design must reduce the Rja to not exceed 85'C at max ambient temperature.

Rule of thumb. If the LED burns your thumb, its' being driven too hard for your thermal design.

BTW Absolute Maximum Ratings only refer to pulsed current @ 25C using a 25'C cold plate.
This means you need the spec or tell us where you got it.